# Python remove multipart header content

Tags: python, multipart

When I try to upload a CSV file and read them, the header content is also added to the csv at the top and at the end of the file :

```
----------------------------1323424324242342
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

<actual content here>

----------------------------113131313331313133--
```

How do I get the actual content in the file and ignore the multipart headers?

Comment: You should use a multipart parser: https://pypi.org/search/?q=multipart

Comment: @MauriceMeyer i am not able to do that as I do not have permissions to change the part where it handles upload, pls advise